# Leaflet Controlls Horizontally

Tags: gis, leaflet

I´ve an problem with placing leaflet controls in my map. I would like to place controls horizontally but I don´t know if is it in Leaflet possible? Is there any solution to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The `leaflet-control` css class looks like that:

```
.leaflet-control {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    }
```

The `clear: both` is what makes the controls go below each other. To prevent that for a certain control, just set `clear:none` on the CSS class for that control, assuming that the control has a specific CSS class you can reach.

Comment: Look at this gist for an example:
https://gist.github.com/mpfeil/3d831e753f7363db6e3e

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet controls are HTML and CSS: use your [web developer extensions](http://debugbrowser.com/), find their classes and IDs, and write CSS that repositions them in a horizontal arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Open leaflet.css, you have ".leaflet-bar a, .leaflet-bar a:hover" in there. You can play with these CSS values. For example add float:left; and they will align horizontally. Look for line 228 or around it depending on leaflet version.

Answer (score 0):

I have found you have to go in to each control and customize the css and position, as well as the .leaflet-top.leaflet-left. You can see an example of what we use at OVRDC here - https://getbounds.com/blog/a-modern-leaflet-toolbar. I would really like to create a horizontal control plugin, where you can add new controls to it, or an array of controls or something, but havent gotten around to it.

Horizontal toolbar image:

[image: Horizontal toolbar image.]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using `react-leaflet`, this is my way to go:

[image]

CSS:

```css
.leaflet-horizontal-bar a {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

.leaflet-horizontal-bar a:first-child {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px !important;
}

.leaflet-horizontal-bar a:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0 !important;
  border-right: none;
}
```

Components:

```js
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import { Box, IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import { MdLocationOn, MdSatellite, MdSpaceDashboard } from "react-icons/md";

{
  mapRef.current && createPortal((
    <Box
      className="leaflet-control leaflet-bar leaflet-horizontal-bar leaflet-control-custom"
      sx={{ clear: "none" }}
    >
      <Box component="a">
        <IconButton size="small">
          <MdSatellite color="black" fontSize={20} />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
      <Box component="a">
        <IconButton size="small">
          <MdSpaceDashboard color="black" fontSize={20} />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
      <Box component="a">
        <IconButton size="small">
          <MdLocationOn color="black" fontSize={20} />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  ), mapRef.current._controlCorners.bottomleft)
}
```